# Differentiating an "admin" level access for a node in Milo OPC UA project?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

While trying to understand the milo project examples for OPC UA based client and server, wanted to get clarified on the following scenario.

When I was trying to test WriteExample with namespace string `HelloWorld/OnlyAdminCanWrite/`
 to connect with server which validates the user with `UserNameIdentityToken` values "admin" (username) and password2 (password), it was not able to write values.

Is it because the identity is not recognized as admin as seen in the following code in the ExampleNamespace.java file?

```
node.setAttributeDelegate(new RestrictedAccessDelegate(identity -> {
    if ("admin".equals(identity)) {
        return AccessLevel.READ_WRITE;
    } else {
        return AccessLevel.READ_ONLY;
    }
```

How to differentiate the admin from the other users? tested attributes like AccessLevel and UserAccessLevel but they are effective on the current user trying to access.

Comment: Are you sure you were writing to the correct NodeId and modified it to connect with admin/password2 credentials? I've just tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the clarification. Yes you are right, I was using the wrong NodeId. The right NodeId is "HelloWorld/OnlyAdminCanWrite/String" and in order to test WriteExample the Variant value to be written should be a String. Now it works !